# robots.txt запретить url по параметру

Tags: robots.txt

Не могу решить проблему с закрытием определенных страниц от индексации в robots.txt

url имеют такой вид:

https://site.info/map?page=stroitelstvo-shkoly&language=en

https://site.info/map?page=sevastopol&language=en

Я пытаюсь в панели вебмастера запретить индексировать все страницы англоязычной версии, и не могу этого сделать. Заявка на удаление имеет статус "отклонено". 
Поискала причину, народ пишет, дело в том, что в robots.txt эти страницы не запрещены.

Отсюда вопрос: как мне прописать директиву, запрещающую индексацию всех страниц, содержащих в url слово "language"?

Пробовала `Disallow:/*language*`, `Disallow:/?language` и `Disallow:/&language`

Ибо там, по словам программиста, какие-то еще тараканы с заменой ? на &.
Все равно в Я.Вебмастере вижу эти страницы открытыми для индексации. И, соответственно, там тоже не могу удалить эти url.
Подскажите, что нужно написать в robots.txt в моем случае.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Использование спецсимволов * и $](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/controlling-robot/robots-txt.html#asterisk-dollar)

> При указании путей директив Allow и Disallow можно использовать
>   спецсимволы * и $, задавая, таким образом, определенные регулярные
>   выражения. Спецсимвол * означает любую (в том числе пустую)
>   последовательность символов.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*&language=en
#Запретит все страницы, содержащие &language=en
```